# Why is this expression ambiguous?

Tags: haskell

Here, I defined two classes `F` and `O`. `F` is for a polymorphic function `f`, and `O` is for a polymorphic value `o`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class F a b where
    f :: a -> b

class O a where
    o :: a

data K = K 
data L = L 
data M = M 

instance O K where
    o = K 

instance O L where
    o = L 

instance F K L where
    f K = L 

instance F L K where
    f L = K 

instance F L L where
    f L = L 

instance F M K where
    f M = K
```

To make it easy, here is a list of possible instances for either class:

```
F K L
F L K
F L L
F M K

O K
O L
```

Now if I type in the following into GHCi:

```
f o :: K
```

I expect Haskell to figure out that since the end result has to be `K`, it means possible instances for `f` are `F M K` and `F L K`, but since `o` can only be a `L` but not `M`, it has to be the case that `o` is `L` and `f` is `F L K`. That is, without any other possibility the result should be `K`. However, it turns out Haskell can't figure this out:

```
*Main> f o :: K

<interactive>:2:1:
    No instance for (F a0 K) arising from a use of `f'
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance F M K -- Defined at hw.hs:28:10
      instance F L K -- Defined at hw.hs:22:10
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (F a0 K)
    In the expression: f o :: K
    In an equation for `it': it = f o :: K

<interactive>:2:3:
    No instance for (O a0) arising from a use of `o'
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance O L -- Defined at hw.hs:16:10
      instance O K -- Defined at hw.hs:13:10
    In the first argument of `f', namely `o'
    In the expression: f o :: K
    In an equation for `it': it = f o :: K
```

Do you think it is because the compiler isn't intelligent enough, or do you think there's actual ambiguity in my expression?

Comment: This is too much to ask.  Remember that type classes are *open*, which means that the code must continue to compile when new instances are added. We could easily add an instance for `O M`, which would make your expression ambiguous, and hence it must already be ambiguous in an open world.  However, the new [closed type families](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families#Closed_family_simplification) extension might do what you want -- I haven't worked with them much so I can't be sure.

Comment: And in fact (using `FlexibleInstances`) you can simply define `x :: O M => K; x = f (o :: M)` and then use `x` in another module that has an `instance O M`. So in that sense the choice of the type of `o` in the expression `f o` really is ambiguous.

Comment: @ReidBarton, do you mean `FlexibleContexts`?

Comment: To stress the point luqui makes: if in another module I do `import YourModule ; instance O M where ...` suddenly `f o` can be implemented in two ways. That should generate an error like "I'm sorry but adding such an instance makes some other code you did not write ambiguous" -- raising eyebrows. This would also require the compiler to remember all these cases of potential problems across modules. Instead, Haskell was designed to reject these cases at the source.

Answer (score 1):

`o` returns any type: `o :: a`.

Feeding it to `f` yields

```
:t f o
  f o :: F a b => b
```

Which means that `a` can be any type here. So `o` is ambiguous.

`f o :: K` states `b` to be `K` in `f :: a -> b` in `F a b`.

Both cases above yields a possible instance for `f`

```
instance F a0 K
```

which has a two candidates

```
instance F L K

instance K M K
```

`o` returns any instance of `O` class. There are only two instances defined:

```
instance O K
instance O L
```

So `f o :: K` is ambiguous 'cause `o` is ambiguous.

---

I think `GHC` infers types in such a way (only searching for suitable instances) in order to do not stuck in a loop. But I'm only started to learn it so I can be wrong here.

There are a techniques described [here](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/HList-ext.pdf) and [here (shortly)](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/AdvancedOverlap) which helps compiler to infer a correct instances.